# Float:; não funcionando CSS

Tags: html, css

Pretendo alinhar esses blocos em linha horizontal, mas o uso do float:; não está atendendo o esperado, qual erro estou cometendo?

```css
.fl > div{ float:left;  }

div:nth-child(1){ position:relative; width:300px; height:300px; background-color:#066;} 
div:nth-child(2){ position:relative; width:300px; height:300px; background-color:#06F;} 
div:nth-child(3){ position:relative; width:300px; height:300px; background-color:#C30;}
```

```html
<div class="fl">
<div class="bk">1</div>
<div class="bk">2</div>
<div class="bk">3</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seu seletor está errado. Deveria ser:

```css
.fl > div{ float:left; }

.fl div:nth-child(1){ position:relative; width:300px; height:300px; background-color:#066;} 
.fl div:nth-child(2){ position:relative; width:300px; height:300px; background-color:#06F;} 
.fl div:nth-child(3){ position:relative; width:300px; height:300px; background-color:#C30;}
```

```html
<div class="fl">
   <div class="bk">1</div>
   <div class="bk">2</div>
   <div class="bk">3</div>
</div>
```

Ao setar `div:nth-child(1)` você está selecionando a própria `div .fl`. Se quiser selecionar os filhos de `.fl`, adicione `.fl` nos seletores `nth-child()`.

**Explicação:**

Como `div` é um seletor genérico, irá selecionar todas, independente do nível:

```
<div class="fl"> nth-child(1)
   <div class="bk">1</div> nth-child(1)
   <div class="bk">2</div> nth-child(2)
   <div class="bk">3</div> nth-child(3)
</div>
```

Veja que existe dois `nth-child(1)`, logo a `div .fl` terá os mesmos estilos em:

```
div:nth-child(1){ position:relative; width:300px; height:300px; background-color:#066;}
```

Logo as `div`s dentro de `.fl` não ficarão lado-a-lado porque a `div .fl` tem a mesma largura `width` de `300px`.

Answer (score 3):

Porque o .fl tem o mesmo tamanho das outras divs 300px.

Melhor usar assim:

```
.fl {width: 100%;}
.fl .bk {float: left;}

.bk:nth-child(1){ position:relative; width:300px; height:300px; background-color:#066;} 
.bk:nth-child(2){ position:relative; width:300px; height:300px; background-color:#06F;} 
.bk:nth-child(3){ position:relative; width:300px; height:300px; background-color:#C30;}

<div class="fl">
    <div class="bk">1</div>
    <div class="bk">2</div>
    <div class="bk">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sem especificar o tamanho do '.fl ' funciona tbm, o bom é que funcionou com display:flex; também

Comment: Sim, funciona. Depende muito da sua finalidade. Mas ainda indicaria em vez de usar px nos .bk utilizaria porcentagem.